# Could not launch new activity, keeps on refreshing

Tags: android

I want to create a simple image button that launches a new activity (CameraActivity), in this case, a simple camera app that takes a pictures and stores it in a directory.

MainActivity:

```
 public void CameraButton() {

    ImageButton Click = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.CameraButton);
    Click.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CameraActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

CameraActivity.class:

```
import java.io.File;

import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CameraActivity extends MainActivity
{

static int TAKE_PIC = 1;
Uri outPutfileUri;

public void onClick(View v)
{

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "MyPhoto.jpg");
    outPutfileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outPutfileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PIC);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PIC && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(this, outPutfileUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

activity_main XML file:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/CameraButton"
    android:background="@drawable/camerapicture"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Every time I click the button, the app keeps on refreshing itself. I have declared the CameraActivity in the manifest file.

Comment: Refreshing because of this "CameraActivity extends MainActivity"
use this "CameraActivity extends Activity"
And why using this  android:onClick="onClick"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your code of CameraActivity

```
import java.io.File;

import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CameraActivity extends Activity
{

static int TAKE_PIC = 1;
Uri outPutfileUri;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_CAMERA_ACTIVITY_LAYOUT);



    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "MyPhoto.jpg");
    outPutfileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outPutfileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PIC);

    }

public void onClick(View v)
{

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "MyPhoto.jpg");
    outPutfileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outPutfileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PIC);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PIC && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(this, outPutfileUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are starting CameraActivity from MainActivity but you extends CameraActivity from MainActivity so in directly CameraActivity starting MainActivity so it look 
 refreshing . for solve this problem you need to extends CameraActivity from Activity class like this

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity
{
  //your Activity body 
}
```

or if you using AppCompact then you need to extends from ActionBarActivity like this

```
 public class CameraActivity extends ActionBarActivity
 {
  //your Activity body 
 }
```

i hop this will help you

Comment: It works, thank you. But now once the button is clicked, a blank page opens instead of executing the activity. Where did I went wrong?

Comment: @User so if it work's then please accept my answer .